# addToBackState() doesn't restore fragment state

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction

When I replace `fragmentA` by `fragmentB` I use this code:

```
 fragmentManager
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.content_frame, new fragmentB())
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .commit();
```

But when I press back button `fragmentA` doesn't keep its previous state but reloads from the beginning. 
How can I restore previous `fragmentA` state?

Comment: what do you mean by "reloads from the beginning" ?

Comment: I load some data into WebView in onCreateView(...) method. And I want this fragment not to load it again but show already loaded data.

Answer (score 0):

You could try overriding the fragment's onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) method. Just save the webview's current url to the bundle and then retrieve it in the fragment's onCreateView method.

```
public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    ...
    if(savedInstanceState != null){
        String url = savedInstanceState.getString("URL");
        if(url != null){
            mWebView.loadUrl(url);
        }
    }
    ...
}

public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){ 
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString("URL", mWebView.getUrl();
}
```